# Player gets stuck when moving across multiple objects that have colliders

Tags: collision-detection, collision, unity-game-engine

For my assignment I have to make a Super Mario Bros NES clone. The issue I am currently having is when mario, the player, runs across multiple brick objects he gets stuck. I assume that is because each individual brick is a prefab, and therefore there are multiple rigidbody2ds and colliders.

I've done some googling and many people recommend adding a circle collider to the bottom of the player, which I tried. I didn't like the result as it created even more issues around movement and player collision with other objects.

Similarly, I've looked at mesh colliders, but it appears to be only for 3d.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem before. You are correct that having many smaller ground colliders is what is messing you up. What you want to do instead of having a platform be composed of multiple individual colliders, have on large collider represent the entire thing.

This is obviously tricky, because the bricks need to be able to be removed individually. What I would look into doing is creating a new game object (a "brick collider manager") that looks for horizontally continuous sections of bricks (probably by iterating through `GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("Brick")`) and creates colliders around them (which probably can either be components of its own game object, or prefabs it instantiates as its children.

Then, when a brick is destroyed, it can just recalculate.